# magento submit attributes to cart page

Tags: magento

color and size which both are multiple select are required in my all products. so i must choose these opinions in tab 'general' so that i do not want to set them in tab 'Custom Options' again.

ex:  in 'general' tab,  blue,red and pink are chosed as color. 8,9 and 10 are chosed as size.
and 'custom options' tab has nothing.  so in the front product view page,  how can i submit values of color and size to cart page after choosing one color and one size ?

anyone have any idea?  thanks .

(i knew, if i set colors and sizes in 'custom options' tab, i can submit values in the front page, but my case is different from this.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure, if I understand you right... 
If I have understood correctly, you want to do the following: Your customer should choose a product by the values "size" and "color" - so the aim is to know wich values the customer has chosen...

This is a typical requirement for a configurable product.

You have to apply every option as a simple product.
product 1: red, 8 / 
product 2: red, 9 /
... /
product 14: green, 8 / 
product 15: green, 9 / 
....

And then you have to apply ONE configurable product, choose color and size as "super"-attributes, and then apply all the simple products to your configurable product.

Now your shopping-customer has to choose his shirt by color and size and his choice will be displayed in the cart, invoice... etc.

Comment: how to choose color and size as "super"-attributes, please ?

Comment: The type of the attribute has to be a "drop down". "Use To Create Configurable Product" has to be "yes". If you now create a new configurable product (based on the attribute set, which contains these attributes), you will be asked by magento which of those attributes are used to differ the product.

Comment: yes, i got you, but if i have a T-shirt， red color has 8,9,10 (size), and blue color also has 8,9,10 (size),  pink has 9 and 10 size,  if like this case, how many products will i need to update ? it seems to need more time and work....

Comment: Ervery option is one simple product - red, 8 is one, red 9 is one, etc. In your example you have to apply 8 simple products and one configurable. The other solution is, to use custom options. Then you only need one product. Most Shop owners don'tuse this, because of the inventory, wich is not detailed enough in this case.